# Using HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML with Headers, Tables, Rows, Cells

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use HtmlAgilityPack to parse through a webpage's HTML to parse out the rows/cells of tables.

The code sample almost works, except I get an exception on the Table collection.  I presume this might have something to do with Header not formatted as a collection (and I cannot modify the source of the HTML).

Please help with the code, or please suggest alternatives or workarounds.

The structure is:
Header -> Table -> Row -> Cell

There are a collection of Headers (which contain the date), that contain collection of Tables, which contain a collection of Rows, and Rows contain a collection of Cells.

```
string html = @"
<html>
<body>
<h3>February 8, 2014</h3>    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Site</b></td>
            <td><b>ColumnA</b></td>
            <td><b>ColumnB</b></td>
            <td><b>ColumnC</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SiteA</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SiteB</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SiteC</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<h3>February 7, 2014</h3>    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Site </b></td>
            <td><b>ColumnA</b></td>
            <td><b>ColumnB</b></td>
            <td><b>ColumnC</b></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SiteA</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SiteB</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SiteC</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (HtmlNode header in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3"))
{
    string headerDate = header.InnerText;

    foreach (HtmlNode table in header.SelectNodes("table"))  //System.NullReferenceException
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
        {
            Console.Write(headerDate);
            foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
            {
                Console.Write("\t" + cell.InnerText);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Results:**

```
February 8, 2014    Site    ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
February 8, 2014    SiteA   3   6   3
February 8, 2014    SiteB   4   6   2
February 8, 2014    SiteC   4   9   4
February 7, 2014    Site    ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
February 7, 2014    SiteA   2   4   1
February 7, 2014    SiteB   1   1   2
February 7, 2014    SiteC   2   6   1
```

Thank you.  Jake.

Comment: *"The code sample almost works"*, please provide your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the headers as if you're expecting the tables to be within the header tags, but the tables are *not* within the header tags, despite what the misleading indentation appears to suggest.  The header tags are **siblings** of the tables, not **parents**.

```
<h3>February 8, 2014</h3>  <-- </h3> closes the header tag
<table>                    <-- this is the next element at the same level, not a child
    <tr>
        <td><b>Site</b></td>
        <td><b>ColumnA</b></td>
        <td><b>ColumnB</b></td>
        <td><b>ColumnC</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Keep in mind that indentation/whitespace is meaningless in html.  It's the tags that rule all.